# SharePoint 2010 People Picker Issues

Tags: active-directory, site-collection, central-administration, people-picker, people-search

I recently performed a database attach upgrade from a SharePoint 2003 system to SharePoint 2007, then up to SharePoint 2010. Everything is running well, for the most part. But one of our biggest problems is the people picker.

It works fine at the root site, http://domain.com. Any sub-sites under that, http://domain.com/sites/site1, which are their own site collection, can only query users that are already a member of the site-collection. In Central Administration, it only works for the user accounts that are setup as managed service accounts or the config service account.

If I manually add a user to a site via powershell, I can then query for that person within the people picker.

A bit about the server architecture. We're running all SharePoint services on a single server, that uses a separate SQL server. These all reside in a forest on domain1. We have a one-way trust setup with domain2 which is in a separate forest.

I have run all of the stsadm commands that should allow cross forest/domain searches, and have also verified peoplepicker-onlysearchwithinsitecollection is set to no on all sites.

I also have userprofile synchronization reading users from both domains without any problems. And as a side note, when people picker does find people, it doesn't always have their full profile information. So sometimes it'll show domain\username, and others it'll show LastName, FirstName.

At this point, I'm not so sure the issue is with cross domain searching, because the root site can see all users in both domains.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. I've spent the better part of two days reading through various articles and running several different commands against the sites to verify there are no AD search filters or restrictions in place.

If you need anymore details, please let me know and I'll do my best to acquire them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you've got it setup right, I was going to suggest have you done the stsadm command that I posted on this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/sharepoint-2010-peoplepicker-control-not-displaying-user-data/40249#comment36808_40249

Comment: I have indeed run the _setapppassword_ and _Peoplepicker-searchadforests_ commands. I feel like the cross domain searching is working, since I am able to run searches at the root site without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this resolved, the issue was with spacing between parameters in setting the peoplepicker-searchadforests property.

I previously was using this:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:domain.local, domain\username, password" -url http://spserver
```

I should have been using this:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:domain.local,domain\username,password" -url http://spserver
```

Notice the spacing after the commas in the first command. There should be no spaces between the domain name, username, and password.